# Phone Number Validation

Tags: javascript

I want to validate a phone number entered by user according to his/her country which I know.
I am using PHP/Javascript/MYSQL in my site.

OR

have anybody list of mobile number format for all countries i.e. area code,country code, minimum and maximum length??

Answer (score 1):

I've been using a free API called [numverify.com](https://numverify.com) - you can request any national or international phone number, and the API will return a simple JSON result containing validation results, country, location, line type infos, and more.

Answer (score 0):

I know about a paid service from [data8](http://www.data-8.co.uk/integr8/services/mobile_validation.aspx)

I am sure there are others out there do a Google for "mobile phone validation api"